# Howto display photo wall when photo's all differ in dimensions (jquery)

Tags: jquery, image, alignment

I am planning to display a **'photo wall'**. The problem is that all photos have different dimensions and orientations (landscape/portrait). For example, when you are searching for photos on stock site Dreamstime.com you'll notice the setup I want to achieve. (http://www.dreamstime.com/photos-images/programming.html). A Google Image search is similar to this.

My question is: how is this done? Is there a jQuery plugin? Or do I need to get all the dimensions and then use a recursive function to fit it in 1 row? Or does 1 image has multiple dimension to get the best fit (when sorting)?

Comment: [Have a look at jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Google Images and your example have all images in a row the same height, which is easily achievable. I suppose what you're really looking for is a way to position images of different widths *and* heights neatly in a grid. If so, check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Finally, thanks! I've been looking for this a long time. However, when I do want the same height, what's the best way to achieve that? Store all dimensions in the database and let the PHP script determine the best order? Or is there also a Jquery plugin for that?

Comment: Masonry works great for same height images too. You may also want to check out [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) and [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) (by the same author), but only Masonry is under MIT license. The others are free for personal use only.

Answer (score 0):

Loading an image 500 X 500 px is a bad idea when you want to show it as 200 X 200 px.
What I woulud suggest is

1. Crop images on the fly on your php server and then serve the optimized images. You can use libraries like imagick http://www.imagemagick.org/ which will do your job.
2. If you have a functionality where you want to show a bigger image when user clicks on the small images then use jquery and other libs to fetch the full size image on click using ajax.

You will find many answers on stackoverflow on how to crop images using imagick.

Happy coding.